# Update a git subtree branch with new commits from the original branch

Tags: git, github, git-subtree

I'm working on dividing part of my main repository into another one. I'm using git subtree to do the work.

So I created a subtree branch with the following command:

```
git checkout master
git subtree split -P ./Foo -b subtreeBranch
```

A new branch is created with the content of Foo, named as `subtreeBranch`.

But later some changes have been added into the original branch(`master`), onto the files inside `Foo`.

How can I update the `subtreeBranch` with the new commits?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix i by running `git subtree split` again on the original branch. As stated in the git subtree [reference](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) regarding split:

> Repeated splits of exactly the same history are guaranteed to be
> identical (i.e. to produce the same commit ids).  Because of this, if
> you add new commits and then re-split, the new commits will be
> attached as commits on top of the history you generated last time, so
> 'git merge' and friends will work as expected.

However running git subtree is a very slow process, probably related to the size of my project.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [subtree merging strategy](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging):

```
git merge -s subtree branch_to_merge
```

Comment: Thanks @knittl, however according to the linked article this approach merges subtree back to master, and I want it the other way around.

Comment: @XunYang: the third-last paragraph states that  "You can also do the opposite — make changes in the rack subdirectory of your master branch and then merge them into your rack_branch branch later to submit them to the maintainers or push them upstream." Git should be clever enough to figure out what to merge. And since everything is local, you can just try if it merges correctly. If it didn't, simply undo the merge.

Comment: Hmm it messes things up royally. diff-tree also not working :/ I tried `git checkout subtreeBranch  git merge -s subtree master`